# Batch file If Exist fails file check

Tags: batch-file

I may be doing something wrong but I have encountered an interesting behavior while scripting a batch file for a build.

I had to script two different paths one for a build machine and one for my development machine so that the script runs correctly when testing.

So I had the following:

```
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\Parent Path\Path A\Subpath\Filename.exe" ( 
   SET VARNAME=<PATH> 
) ELSE ( 
   IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\Parent Path\Path B\Subpath\Filename.exe" (
      SET VARNAME=<PATH> 
   )
)
```

On the development machine the path should be Path B, Path A does not exist. Yet the parent path does exist on both machines, and the subpath is the same. But the application path is NOT the same. They are unique paths in Windows.

On the development machine if I include the 'Filename.exe' in the IF EXISTS expression, the statement always returns true for Path A even though Path A does not exist on the development machine. If I remove Filename.exe, which is how I resolved my problem, the path returns false for Path A and True for Path B.

I am making an assumption that the application is installed correctly and that Filename.exe is present for the build system, since now I cannot accurately test for it.

Has anyone else seen any behavior like this or is there something else that i could have done to change the behavior?

EDIT: I should mention that this is on Windows XPsp3
EDIT: Reformatted the code to reflect my actual batch file format, and to avoid confusion others had from my quick type up. Dummy me made assumptions :D

Comment: Are these two lines? `)`, `else` and `(` have to be on the same line.

Comment: there's also missing quote on the second if...

Comment: in my actual code the quotes are there. Sorry for not quoting in the sample here. :D Yes, these formatted correctly in the BATCH file.

Comment: I had this issue in my batch file when I didn't include the .exe extension in my path. While executing running "c:\program files\thing" worked just fine, checking for its existence failed when ".exe" was missing from "thing.exe". Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\Parent Path\Path A\Subpath\Filename.exe" (
  SET VARNAME=<PATH>
) ELSE (
  IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\Parent Path\Path B\Subpath\Filename.exe" (
    SET VARNAME=<PATH>
  )
)
```

Comment: This is basically what I have. If I remove the 'Filename.exe', then the check works. If I include Filename.exe then the batch file will always say that Path A exists when it does not. REMEMBER: In this test I do not change anything but just remove the 'Filename.exe'. I do not modify the structure of the IF EXIST ( ) ELSE ( ) statement. The only reason I thought to try this was because I use this method to test for the Program Files (x86) folder on 64bit systems and it has been working successfully for some time.

Comment: This code works correctly. There must be more happening in the batch file or a misunderstanding between what you're asking and what I'm hearing.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\Parent Path\Path A\Subpath\Filename.exe" ( 
    SET VARNAME=<PATH> 
) ELSE ( 
  IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\Parent Path\Path B\Subpath\Filename.exe" ( 
    SET VARNAME=<PATH> 
  )
)
```

Cannot start a line with `ELSE` because there's no such command (it always must be paired with if).Also missing quote on the second if.

Comment: I just had it shown this way here for easier reading guys so people did not have to scroll. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: the only thing that comes to me at the moment is to check with `enableDelayedExpansion` -->> `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`  `IF EXIST "!PROGRAMFILES!\Parent Path\Path A\Subpath\Filename.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

If that is the exact task then this is the same logic.

```
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\Parent Path\Path B\Subpath\Filename.exe" SET "VARNAME=<PATHB>"
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES%\Parent Path\Path A\Subpath\Filename.exe" SET "VARNAME=<PATHA>"
```